# Creating Hibernate Restriction for 'between' Strings

Tags: java, hibernate

I'd like to compare if a String is greater than or equal and less than or equal another two Strings.

Example:

> "C" between "A" and "F" > true

I tried:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria();
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("START_VALUE_COLUMN", "C")) 
        .add(Restrictions.le("END_VALUE_COLUMN", "C"));
```

But that's not working for me.

How can I add this `Restriction` in Hibernate?

Comment: Which of those are literals, and which are column names?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I just updated - thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear. If `C` is the column, and `A` and `F` are values, you can use `Restrictions.between("C", A, F)`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidWallace C is the value, A and F are columns.

Comment: @JimmyT. If that's the case, then all the OP needs to do to make this work is to swap `ge` and `le`.  He has simply got them the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have you have swapped the operators.

Your criteria results in:

```
... where START_VALUE_COLUMN >= "C" and END_VALUE_COLUMN <= "C"
```

Turn them around:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria();
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("START_VALUE_COLUMN", "C")) 
        .add(Restrictions.ge("END_VALUE_COLUMN", "C"));
```

Comment: "C" is between start and end. That means start <= "C" <= end.

Comment: Ah, so the `Restrictions.ge` means that the comparedToField is >= the property. So `Restrictions.ge("END_VALUE_COLUMN", "C")` means "END_VALUE_COLUMN" is >= "C"?

Comment: `Restrictions.ge` means `END_VALUE_COLUMN > 'C'` where `END_VALUE_COLUMN` is a column/property and `'C'` is a string literal/value. It that what you were asking?